# How can i let a user choose between, let's say 5 items in any order they wish in C#?

Tags: c#, switch-statement

im trying to give my user 5 options on console and i want them to be able to choose more than one option from the menu.
i've calculated that there are 31 ways a user can choose between 5 choices.
im trying to write a switch/case for it but writing 31 cases for it doesn't seem logical.
what are other ways of doing it?
i would aprreciate you guys helping me with this

```
namespace Homework_2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("a-cake b-milk c-noodles d-cheese e-coke:");
            string choice = Console.ReadLine();
            switch (choice)
            {
                default:
                    break;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you edit your question to show us the code you've started on? How are you reading the user's input? How are you determining which choices have been selected?

Comment: What's an example of the input you're expecting the user to give?

Comment: Use a loop:  `foreach (var choice in Console.ReadLine().Split()) { /*switch*/  }`

Comment: look i want them to choose between the items and then give me the quantity they want and then i calculate the prices and give them a reciept

Comment: Please clearly state a few sample inputs and update the original post.

Comment: What is a *specific example* of the input you want the user to type? Are you expecting them to type letters? Words separated by spaces? Separated by commas? You need to figure out what you want the program to do before you can tell the computer to do what you want.

Comment: i want them to put letters with commas for example like: "a,b" or "a,d,e" and then accordingly i tell the computer what to do

Answer (score -1):

It appears that you want to ask the user to input multiple choices, and then do something with the selections. It also seems you have price/cost associated with each item, so I would consider using a `3-Tuple` in this case.

```
var options = new List<Tuple<int, string, int>>
{
    Tuple.Create( 1, "Cake", 100 ),
    Tuple.Create( 2, "Milk", 200 ),
    Tuple.Create( 3, "Noodles", 300 ),
    Tuple.Create( 4, "Cheese", 400 ),
    Tuple.Create( 5, "Coke", 500 )
};
```

First is the choices you want the user to input, second is the item name, and the third is the unit price.

Then ask the user to input their choices separated by a comma:

```
Console.WriteLine("Select one or more options seperated by a comma");
foreach (var opt in options)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", opt.Item2, opt.Item1);
}
var selection = Console.ReadLine();
```

Next, we'll split the user input by comma and iterate through them. Obviously if you want a good program you'd have to do error handling here in case user gives a bad input, but this is just for illustration.

```
var items = selection.Split(',');
foreach (var item in items)
{
    if (int.TryParse(item, out int value))
    {
        // We're looking in the 'options' list if we have the selection the user made
        var option = options.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Item1 == value);
        if (option != null)
        {
            // If it does exist, do what you want with it. Here I'm merely printing them.
            Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1} - {2}", option.Item1, option.Item2, option.Item3);
        }
    }
}
```